# How to use Collect Values and Tabulate Areas in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, data-collection

I have problems with the **[Tabulate Area](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w2000000)** tool.

The polygons in my shapefile overlap and because of this ArcMap does not calculate proper values.

I try to solve this using ModelBuilder where it is possible to do the **[Tabulate Area](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w2000000)** for each polygon separately but at the end I would like to combine rows back to one table.

I thought that the solution may be the model only tool called **[Collect Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004000000005000000)**?

Can someone help me how to add rows to one table or to save each **[Tabulate Area](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w2000000)** result under different names?

I hope that the question is understandable. If not, I will try to rewrite it.

Here is also a picture.

[image]

Comment: Are you perhaps able to include a few pictures that illustrate what you are trying to do in more detail using a very simple example of perhaps just two polygons that overlap?  I've +1-ed your Question in case you need a little more reputation to include pictures.

Comment: FYI, you added links in your question to the ArcGIS 10.2 help files but you tagged your question with ArcGIS 10.0, you may want to clarify what version you're using.

Comment: PolyGeo thank you for editing. User2856159 - I'm using ArcGIS 10.0. Thank you for help.

Comment: I found the answer how to save results under different names by using tools "Get Field Value" and "Parse Path".

Comment: @MtS, Could you please post your answer so others can benefit?

Comment: @user2856159 It was me that added the 10.2 help links and I did that rather than use the 10.0 help because, being online, the documentation usually gets enhanced at a rate faster than the software and most (usually all) of it will apply equally to the earlier versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the result that worked for me. Still I had to use R later to combine the dbf files into one single long file.
[image]

Comment: If you feed the output of your tabulate area tool into a collects tool and expose that as a parameter then the whole model can become a sub-model which feeds into a merge tool, so no need for using R. Have a look at my answer to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78971/iterate-through-multiple-raster-files-and-compute-statistics-using-zonal-statist/79014#79014) to see what I'm talking about as it is similar.