# How to use ModelBuilder to add many images to mosaic dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, imagery

Here is my sample of a model builder. [image]What I would like to create a mosaic dataset then add lots lots lots lots of imagery from different folders to the dataset rather than I have to do manually.

What I would like to run tool to add the imagery to the dataset and when it is done then change to another folder and keep adding more imagery without having to stop the process builder. Is there a tool to do that or should I need to create a variable ?

There are three folders that hold imagery and there are three sub-folders as well.

You can see why I am trying to build three different names: Columbus, El Paso, and Playas Valley because it is where they hold the imagery.

Comment: Everyone I do know how to do that but how do I add a variable or a tool that allows me to run one process and then when the first process is done and then move to the next process. I have three sets.

Comment: Are your 3 folders of images all sub-folders to a folder or completely different drive locations? If they are all sub- folders consider using the iterate raster tool collecting them with a collects tool then pass that to a single instance of add raster to mosaic dataset. It will require you to create a sub-model, look at this [thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78971/iterate-through-multiple-raster-files-and-compute-statistics-using-zonal-statist/79014#79014) to understand

Comment: Yes, three different folder under C drive.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest thing would be to add all 3 folders into one tool.  The dialog box for Add Rasters To Mosaic Dataset will allow you to add multiple folders.

[image]

Comment: +1 @PROBERT should be able to use Contents part of Catalog window to multiple select these for drag and drop onto the tool dialog