# Calculate Field in ModelBuilder gives General error executing calculator. ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Expected end of statement?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, error-999999

I am attempting to do zonal statistics for multiple images and I need to add an extra field that will have the name of each raster file in each row to the finally appended file. I have added a field before appending but when I run the model it fails to do this. I get the following error:

> General error executing calculator.
>   ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   Expected end of statement
>   Failed to execute (Calculate Field).

The expression in the calculate field is `%Name%`. I have followed the instructions on [Iterate through multiple Raster files and compute statistics using Zonal Statistics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78971/iterate-through-multiple-raster-files-and-compute-statistics-using-zonal-statist/79256#79256) and [Iterate zonal statistics table model builder - add field and name each row by raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102588/iterate-zonal-statistics-table-model-builder-add-field-and-name-each-row-by-ra)

The raster files are tiff files with long names e.g. *MCD43B3.A2002001.h21v09.005.2007114212806.hdf.tif* and I am interested in the name because it has the datestamp "A2002001". I need this included in the final appended Table so I can know for which date the zonal statistics belong.

In calculate field, under the expression I typed `%Name%` and choose the calculate field that was added in the file *bsa_20021*. This follows the advice given in the threads [Iterate through multiple Raster files and compute statistics using Zonal Statistics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78971/iterate-through-multiple-raster-files-and-compute-statistics-using-zonal-statist/79256#79256) and [Iterate zonal statistics table model builder - add field and name each row by raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102588/iterate-zonal-statistics-table-model-builder-add-field-and-name-each-row-by-ra)

For some reason, it is not clear how this is supposed to work.

[image: See attached image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is in the interpretation:

```
%Name%
```

Expands out to the name of the feature class so the field calculation is looking for a field that matches the name of the feature class, is unable to find one, then returns an error as no field called *MCD43B3.A2002001.h21v09.005.2007114212806.hdf.tif* exists in the feature class.

To use the name of the feature class as a string calculation it is necessary to quote it, this informs field calculation tool that you want to calculate a *string* and not a *field*:

```
"%Name%"
```

Expands to "MCD43B3.A2002001.h21v09.005.2007114212806.hdf.tif" which is a string and the field calculation tool will put that string into the field - provided the field is long enough to store the data.

That is a very long file name... the default string length is 50 and there's less than 50 characters there but if your file names become longer then be aware of that; shapefiles can have up to 250 characters in the string fields, databases it's over 4 billion (the entire text of a medium library, we calculated it during a power outage) so it's unlikely to overflow that!