# Summarizing multiple raster values by polygon

Tags: python, raster, polygon, r

I have seen several discussions about zonal statistics and similar processes for summarizing rasters by polygons, however I have a question that I can't seem to find an answer to. Most of these past questions ask about summarizing 1 raster at a time.

Currently I have about 60 separate raster files (ascii but can be converted to .tif if needed) and polygon shapefile counties for several states. I would like to summarize the 60 rasters by county. I imagine the attribute table will have each county as a row and the mean of each raster as columns.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems the zonal statistics tool only does 1 raster at a time and batch processing wouldn't fix that. Also, I believe the zonal statistics tool output is a raster, correct? I would like the results of each raster to be added to the polygon shapefile attribute table.

Is there another way to do this? I am open to python or R solutions.

Comment: Just write a loop over your rasters? What's the problem?

Comment: Ok, I guess that sounds reasonable. I assume this is what I'm looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986206/multiple-rasters-in-zonal-statistics-in-a-for-loop

I haven't done it before myself, but it looks simple enough. I was just hoping there would be a tool for this kind of thing.

Comment: Upon using the zonal stats loop, that isn't the tool I'm looking for, it creates a single raster output with the zonal stats. I want the raster values to be appended to the shapefile attributes, like the multi-value to points tool, but with polygons and statistics.

Comment: Do you want to use "extract"?

Comment: No, I want to calculate the mean for 60 rasters by counties and join all 60 means to the county shapefile. 

I've found this thread, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78971/iterate-through-multiple-raster-files-and-compute-statistics-using-zonal-statist/79256#79256

But I haven't been able to get a working model yet.

Comment: `extract(raster, polys, fun=mean)` will compute raster mean for polygon features. Is that what you want to do, over 60 rasters?

Comment: Is that an R function? I did not know that was the extract you were referring. I can try looping that.

Comment: Its in the raster package - `library(raster);help(extract)` should show you the way...

Comment: No need to loop with `extract`, just `stack()` the layers (the stack will just be virtual, so no new file will be created) and run `extract(raster, polys, fun=mean, sp=TRUE)`