# Combining zonal statistics of multiple rasters into a single table ArcGIS Pro

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, zonal-statistics

I have a collection of 22 raster images from which I need to find the min, max, and mean, and put the results from each image into a single combined table.

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78971/iterate-through-multiple-raster-files-and-compute-statistics-using-zonal-statist/79256#79256) is very similar to what I am wanting to do. However, the answers do not seem to work for me. Additionally, I am working on ArcGIS Pro, which is why I have decided to make this a new question.

I am working in model builder and this is what my model currently looks like:

[image]

The answers say that after this step, this model needs to be made the sub-model of a new model that **appends** the collected tables to a new table. This is where I encounter my problem. The collected output cannot be used as it does not show up as a variable. I have made it a parameter but this does not help.

[image]

I have broken the problem up into steps and it all works perfectly until the collect values and append part.

I have experienced some bugs with ArcGIS Pro and was wondering if it not appearing as a variable is one of them.

Is there a different way of doing this? Or am I do something wrong?

EDIT:

I have managed to get the Output values of the Collect Values tool to appear in the super-model. However, it still cannot be used as a variable. I cannot find an option on Pro to turn a parameter into a variable.

Comment: @BERA I still face the problem with the output of the collect values not appearing as a variable. And if I merge straight out of the Zonal Statistics process (i.e. skipping collect values), it merges it to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered a solution. This skips the Collect Values step and goes straight to Append. This means the issue of the missing variable is not encountered. It is also quicker and less computationally exhaustive.

When using append, you need to create a *blank table* in Catalogue that will be used to append the data to. NOTE: Your blank table **needs** to have the same field names as the input data for this to work. Make sure you create and edit the table to include these. This is where I was going wrong as I was getting a blank output.

[image]