# Zonal statistics as table on multiple rasters in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, ndvi

I have time series of NDVI for 35 years and I  am trying to generate mean and median for five years moving averages(2017, 2020, ...2021) using the zonal statistics as a table tool. I am confused since it takes only one input raster. Please how can I achieve this task?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299070/combining-zonal-statistics-of-multiple-rasters-into-a-single-table-arcgis-pro?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give no detail about how your data is organised or format so any answers suggested will be making some assumptions.

I'm going to assume you have 35 tif files in a folder.

You can use model builder to process this very easily, a single raster iterator feeding into the zonal stats tool will generate the output you require.